# C# WPF - create columns from dictionary keys and bind column values to dictionary values

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, radgridview

My ViewModel contains

```
public ObservableCollection<MyResultRowsViewModels> ResultRows {get;set;}
public ObservableCollection<string> MyDictionaryKeys => ResultRows.SelectMany(x=>x.MyDictionary.Select(y=>y.Keys)).ToObservableCollection();
```

Where `MyResultRowsViewModels`, `ItemSource` of `RadGridView`, contains

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> MyDictionary {get;set;}
```

In xaml.cs file I am trying to generate columns with headers from `MyDictionaryKeys` with values from `MyDictionary[MyDictionaryKey]`

```
public void OnGetData(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var myKeys = ViewModel.MyDictionaryKeys;
    foreach (var name in myKeys)
    {
        MyRadGridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
                                                         {
                                                             Header = name,
                                                             IsReadOnly = true,
                                                            DataMemberBinding  = new Binding($"MyDictionary[\"{name}\"]");
                                                         });
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, it's not working because `MyDictionary[name]` is not a property. So is there any way to bind column to dictionary value or any workaround?

I've tried something like this
in MyResultRows

```
public string CurrentlyFormingColumnName {get;set;}
public decimal MyProperty => MyDictionary[CurrentlyFormingColumnName]
```

and in View

```
foreach (var name in myKeys)
    {
        ViewModel.MyResultRows.ForEach(x=>x.CurrentlyFormingColumnName = name);
        MyRadGridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewDataColumn()
                                                         {
                                                             Header = name,
                                                             IsReadOnly = true,
                                                            DataMemberBinding = new Binding("MyProperty");
                                                         });
    }
```

But because `MyProperty` of an instance of `ResultRow` is changing each time a new column creates, in every created there will be value of last column of an instance

Comment: Why can't you make `MyDictionary` a property? How is it currently defined?

Comment: Edited. My dictionary is a property, but MyDictionary[someKey] - is not a property

Comment: `MyDictionary[someKey]` should work then. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following binding should work assuming `MyDictionary` is a `Dictionary<string, decimal>` property that contains a `name` key:

```
new Binding($"MyDictionary[{name}]")
```

Note the absence of quotes around the key in the binding path.

Comment: It's not working for me for some reason. But I found out, that if MyDictionary is Dictionary<int,decimal>, then Binding is working

Comment: What is the value of `name`?

Comment: As you can see in my post, name is string. But, if I had Dictionary with int keys, I could do binding I want to

Comment: It certainly works for me so you are doing something wrong.